# Code for unchecking checkbox

Tags: apex

Hi I have some fields in my sfdc object record which include a check box field .

my requirement is if i click the checkbox field in a particular record and save it, the remaining all check box fields in all other records should turn off

regards.

my visual force page code

```
<apex:page controller="ofconnect" standardStylesheets="true">
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="CONNECTION BUILDER" tabStyle="connection_OF__c">
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:inputField value="{!connectionfields.Name}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!connectionfields.Host__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!connectionfields.Analytics_Path__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!connectionfields.Port__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!connectionfields.Active__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<center>
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!consave}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!concancel}"/>
</center>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="List of Connections" collapsible="false" >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!connections}" var="cc" style="width:840px;">

<apex:column headerValue="Connection name" width="300">
<apex:outputField value="{!cc.Name}"></apex:outputField>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Host" width="500">
<apex:outputField value="{!cc.Host__c}"></apex:outputField>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Port" width="300">
<apex:outputField value="{!cc.Port__c}"></apex:outputField>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Active">
<apex:outputField value="{!cc.Active__c}"></apex:outputField>
</apex:column>


</apex:pageBlockTable>


</apex:pageBlockSection>


</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My apex class

```
public class ofconnect
{
connection_OF__c cf = new connection_OF__c();


public connection_OF__c  getconnectionfields()
{
    return cf;
}

List<connection_OF__c> connections = [select  Name,Host__c,Port__c,Active__c from connection_OF__c];

public List<connection_OF__c> getconnections()
{
    return connections;
}

public pagereference consave()
{
    connections.add(cf);
    insert cf;

    cf = new connection_OF__c();
    cf.clear();
    return null;

}

public pagereference concancel()
{
    return null;
}




}
```

trigger code

```
trigger active on connection_OF__c (before insert,after update) 
{
for(connection_OF__c  con:trigger.new)
{
List<connection_OF__c> conlist = [select id,Name,Active__c,Analytics_Path__c,Host__c,Port__c from connection_OF__c where Active__c=true ];

List<connection_OF__c> con1list = new List<connection_OF__c>();

if(conlist.size()>0)
{
for(connection_OF__c con1:conlist)
{
if(con.Active__c==true)
{
con1.Active__c= false;
con1list.add(con1);
}
}
update con1list;
}
}}
```

Comment: Hi bharat, welcome to SFSE. You will get a much better response if you include code snippets of what you have so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: trigger active on connection_OF__c (before insert,after update) 
{
for(connection_OF__c  con:trigger.new)
{
List<connection_OF__c> conlist = [select id,Name,Active__c,Analytics_Path__c,Host__c,Port__c from connection_OF__c where Active__c=true ];

List<connection_OF__c> con1list = new List<connection_OF__c>();

if(conlist.size()>0)
{
for(connection_OF__c con1:conlist)
{
if(con.Active__c==true)
{
con1.Active__c= false;
con1list.add(con1);
}
}
update con1list;
}
}}

Comment: this i my vf page code . The problem is the checkboxes are getting updated only after refreshing the page.

Comment: If you click edit under your question you will be able to add the code that way, with much better formatting as well.

Comment: @bharat: You need to explain your requirement better. If you want your VF page to update before saving, you'll want to use JavaScript, otherwise you'll have to save the record and then update the page.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackexchange now i have updated can u please check that

Answer (score 1):

As I see your problem there are three parts to the solution.

1. See if the Active flag is set at all - Assumption: if many records have the flag set we only leave the first record set
2. Update all the records that have come in on the Trigger.new property
3. Go through all the other connection records that weren't in the Trigger.new property

As we are looking to change the values of the records that are being updated we need to use a before trigger. And as these records have been edited we need to exclude them from the larger update too.

These three steps give rise to code in your trigger that looks something like this: please note I haven't actually compiled this anyway, so it might have some typos in it.

```
trigger ClearFlagsTrigger on connection_OF__c (before insert, before update) {

    Boolean flagSet = false;

    for(connection_OF__c con : Trigger.new){
        if(con.Active__c){
            flagSet = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!flagSet)
        return;

    flagSet = false;
    for(connection_OF__c con : Trigger.new){

        if(con.Active__c){
            if(flagSet)
                con.Active__c = false;
            else
                flagSet = true;
        }

        con.Host__c = false;
        con.Port__c = false;

    }   

    List<connection_OF__c> updates = new List<connection_OF__c>();
    for(connection_OF__c con : [SELECT Id, Active__c, Host__c, Port__c FROM connection_OF__c WHERE Id NOT IN Trigger.new]){
        con.Active__c = false;
        con.Host__c = false;
        con.Port__c = false;
        updates.add(con);
    } 

    update con;

}
```

I'm not too sure how you want the actual page to work so I won't comment on your controller.